# Launching program w/posix_openpt() call from script

Tags: c, linux, bash, terminal

I have a program that relies on a psuedo terminal that uses

```
term = posix_openpt()

grantpt(term)

unlockpt(term)

open(term)
```

to open a psuedo terminal. I'll call this program psuedoTerminal.bin

I want to open psuedoTerminal.bin from a bash script, in the following fashion (or similar)

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/sh -c psuedoTerminal.bin &
```

The problem is when my program arrives to the posix_openpt() call, the behaviour is erratic, sometimes CPU consumption arrives to 100%, but it never works. I believe ssh, telnet, etc suffer from the same problems on opening psuedo terminals from inside scripts.

How can I run this program from inside a script? Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179151/50240

Comment: Doesn't work for me, even if it did, it does not appear the correct way to accidentally create a tty.

Comment: So, post actual code, actual results, uname, etc.

Comment: What exactly is it you want? I posted all parts of the relevant code and said it's behavior...

Comment: Why are you writing a `bash` script that just calls `/bin/sh`, instead of using `#!/bin/sh` and running `pseudoTerminal.bin` by itself?

Comment: For starters, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and output of `uname -a`.

Comment: bishop - This has nothing to do with the answer, which I've already found is zsh zpty.